# Is there anything similar to FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT for older APIs?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have a couple activities that are designed to look and act like dialogs (but can't actually be dialogs due to limitations with widgets). These activities use an extension of the Theme.Dialog theme to appear as pop-ups on screen without filling the entire screen.

My goal is that they will mimic dialogs in their appearance such that they'll show on top of whatever is currently on screen, with everything that was on screen still showing up behind the dialog.

In API 21, I can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT in my intent to make the activity do exactly this. However, my app supports as low as API 16. I've tried a couple other flags, but none of them except NEW_DOCUMENT give me the proper appearance. All the others end up opening my actual app behind the dialog activity, then leaving it open once my activity is finished(). Not a deal-breaker, but not ideal.

Are there any tricks I can do to keep my design in a backwards-compatible fashion?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get pretty close by using ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK combined with NEW_TASK. This ensured that any existing tasks for my activity are shut down and a new task is created, ensuring my app doesn't show up in the background.

Unfortunately, this comes with the annoying side-effect of wiping out my users current state, but given that I'll be using this for widgets (where they're already on the homescreen), I doubt it'll be that impactful.

Still, I wrapped the intent flag setting in a check for build version so at least 5.0+ users aren't affected by the annoyance:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        pIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
    }
    else{
        pIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }
```